# find values of a and b for the absolute valued function $f : x \to |x-a| + b$

Tags: functions, relations

How to find values of *a* and *b* for the *absolute valued function*:

**f : x -> |x-a| + b**,

**for values:**  f(3) = 3, f(-1) = 3?

I am student of O'Levels. In my book additional mathematics, in chapter Functions and in the topic Absolute Value Functions.
I have tried it like this:

(i)  **f(3) = 3**

|3 - a| + b = 3

3 - a + b = 3      OR   -3 + a + b = 3

-a + b = 0         OR    a + b = 6

adding (-a + b = 0) into (+a + b = 6)

=> 2b = 6

=> **b = 3** and hence **a=3**  (a+b=6 => a+3 = 6)

these values are different than the book which say a=1 and b=1

Answer (score 1):

we have

$f(3)=|3-a|+b=3$

and

$f(-1)=|-1-a|+b=3$.

this gives

$|3-a|=|-1-a|$ and

$3-a=1+a$ which gives

$\color{red}{a=1}$

$\color{red}{b=1}$.

so

$\color{green}{f(x)=|x-1|+1}$.

check

$f(3)=|3-1|+1=3$.

$f(-1)=|-1-1|+1=|2|+1=3$.
Correct !.